# Swift 2: SKAction to change y position

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a SKAction that changes the y position of a sprite. The sprite is affected by gravity towards the right, and when i set the x position in the SKAction to the sprite's position the sprite movement is slowing down while the Action is running.

How can i change this so that the x movement is not effected by the action running?

```
let moveDown = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: player.position.x, y: 0), duration: 0.3)
    player.runAction(moveDown)
```

Comment: ...this action is moving on the X axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using this code:

```
   let moveDown = SKAction.moveToY(0, duration: 0.3)
    player.runAction(moveDown)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using linearDamping. I'm not sure this is exactly what you're looking for, but it's a property that reduces the body’s linear velocity.

```
player.physicsBody!.linearDamping  = 0.0
```

Let me know if this works for you or if this wasn't what you were looking for!